# Document Management System

Tags: document-management

Is there any Document Management System in Ubuntu?

I tried Alfresco, RavenDB, Owl, Document Manager.

Alfresco, RavenDB are heavy. More than my requirements.
Owl having source issues.
Document Manager im trying to install.

- Should keep data on the same machine as I am looking for more of internal purpose.
- Should allow to upload Zip files as well. If it extracts Zip it will be a great +
- Should allow to send email to preconfigured email addresses
- Should allow to upload data of size around 100MB at one go
- Should maintain history of documents also deleted documents
- Should allow role based document access.
- Should be Free :)
- It should not do any spoofing on data. Documents are confidential.

Please share your knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Nuxeo DM? It fulfills most of points you mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[LogicalDOC](http://www.logicaldoc.com)** offers both Community(free) and Commercial editions. We used it for some customers and in comparison with Alfresco we can state that LogicalDOC is more easy and lightweight, moreover the support service on the Commercial edition is very fast.

It has a very well documented WebService we used to integrate [LogicalDOC](http://www.logicaldoc.com) with ERP and CRM.

Answer (score 2):

**OpenDocMan** is a free, open source web-based PHP document management system (DMS) designed to comply with ISO 17025 and OIE standard for document management. It features web based access, fine grained control of access to files, and automated install and upgrades. [source](http://www.opendocman.com/)

**Kordil EDMS** is  open source, free for commercial and private use, powerful and user friendly Electronic Document Management Software with power-tools that collects all the files of  your organizations under a single meeting point. [source](http://www.kordil.net/)

Also you can use KnowledgeTree Document Management. download from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kt-dms/files/latest/download)

More you can use **bitfarm-Archiv Document Management** which is an ppen Source Document Management System and ECM Software. [source](http://www.bitfarm-archiv.com/)

Comment: ya.. I tried this too. It will store my data online. Data should be stored locally.

Comment: see the others(updated)

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with Alfresco and implemented two projects. None of the two clients that come with it is really useful. I hated both and the company I worked for in the meantime developed their own client.

Customizing is complicated and not upgrade-save. Unfortunately real DMS and ECM is still an area where the Windows-plattform offers more (but mostly not open source).

Your use case is interesting to me. If you find your solution, let me know!

You could also try letodms (in the repositories - http://www.letodms.com/). I did not try it so far (just looked at the demo on their site).

Found also Mayan: http://www.mayan-edms.com/features/
And (mentioned in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12388868): http://www.dspace.org/

Comment: ya sure... I will check :)

Comment: The above mentioned bitfarm is Windows-only BTW.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenKM](http://www.openkm.com/en/) has two versions: a community version (free) and another full professional version.

Both versions are compatible with Linux and Windows. You can find installation information in the [OpenKM Wiki](http://wiki.openkm.com).